# Where to find Facial Visual Object Class

Tags: data-mining, dataset, data, image-classification

I am trying to make a face/head detection model using YOLO and darkflow.
In order to do this I need a set of images peoples face annotated in Visual Object Class, VOC format. I would prefer data set with face from lots of different angles and I am looking to train the model on about 1000~3000 data sets.
I've been doing some googling to find if there are any good data but have been failing to find any. I wanted to ask if someone knew a good source of them before I head on a journey to label over 1000 images.

For those who are looking to do the same.I have found some good pre-trained models.
1. [YOLO-Face-detection](https://github.com/dannyblueliu/YOLO-Face-detection)
2. [YoloKerasFaceDetection](https://github.com/abars/YoloKerasFaceDetection)

I found 1. a little bit inaccurate for my project, it detects fine with threshold of about 0.1 but I believe it can still be improved with more data.
The method 2 is trained to do more than just detect faces.